# Unable to print by using awk command in the shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting-language

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Number of hosts entered are "$#
echo "Hostnames are "$@
for i in "$@"
do
    echo "Logging in to the host "$i
    pbsh root@$i '
    ipaddr=`ip r | awk '{print $9}'`
    if [ ipaddr = 172.*.*.* ]
    then
        echo "Script can not be run in this IP series"
        exit
    else
        cd /var/tmp ; wget http://**********
    fi'
done
```

After executing the above script it is throwing below error. The script is getting execute but not in the desired way.

> awk: cmd. line:1: {print
>
> awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string

I am newbie to the scripting. Kindly correct me if anything wrong in the script.

Comment: Your main problem is the `'` at the end of `pbsh`, which is ended by another `'` in your `awk`, so you probably want to escape the latter by doing `\'`. Another thing is your `if` statement, which will never be true unless you check against the variable `$ipaddr` instead of **ipaddr** string.

Answer (score 0):

In the listing which you posted, the opening single quote in the `pbsh` line is closed by single quote immediately followed by the `awk` command. You can escape the latter by prefixing it with a backslash.

If pbsh also accepts the command to be executed from stdin, an alternative would be to use a HERE document (see the bash man-page, section *Here Documents*).

UPDATE: Gordon Davisson is right in his comment. `\'` doesn't work either. pbsh insists on getting the command to be executed as a single argument, you could either fiddle around with the quotes, as he suggested, or put the whole input for pbsh into a separate file and use, i.e.,

```
pbsh root@$i $(<input_script.pbsh)
```

Comment: Escaping with a backslash does not work in a single-quoted string. You'd need to end the single-quoted string, then use an escaped single-quote, then start a new single-quoted string. Something like this: `awk '\''{print $9}'\''`. If the `pbsh` command accepts it, a here document (with a quoted delimiter) would be simpler.

Comment: It worked after modifying like awk '\''{print $9}'\''. But the script is displaying the if statement block completely while executing. I will check and use here document. Hope it will be good.

Comment: @Veer: Note my updated answer. Maybe this leads to a more maintainable solution.